# How to execute a function after loading a component in Reactjs + MobX?

Tags: reactjs, store, mobx, mobx-react

I am new at working with React + MobX, so I don't fully understand how they work yet.

I want the function `getUserDataFromAPI()` (in `ProfileStore`) to be executed only when I go to `http://localhost:3000/profile`and the component `ProfileComponent` is loaded.

Here's what I have now:

Several Stores are initialized inside a rootStore.

#### RootStore.js

```
class RootStore {
    constructor() {
        this.profileStore = new ProfileStore(this)

        [other randomStores]
    }
}
```

And then, in the `ProfileStore.js` I have:

#### ProfileStore.js

```
constructor(rootStore) {
    this.rootStore = rootStore
    
    runInAction('Load Profile', async () => {
        await this.getUserDataFromAPI()
    });
}
```

I still don't understand what runInAction does, but the main problem is that `ProfileStore's constructor` gets executed regardless of the Component I am loading because it gets initialized with `rootStore`.

How can I make that function to execute only when I navigate to `/profile` and the `Profile Component` is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a `componentDidMount` method.

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.profileStore = new ProfileStore(this)
}
```

Which will be executed once on component MOUNT, not on component creation.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: Then, should I remove the ProfileStore declaration from the RootStore and place the componentDidMount() at the beginning of the Component file? I've read in the MobX docs that having a single rootStore to initialize them all is good practice. Again, it is probable that I didn't understand it right. What do you think?

Comment: I'd keep it in componentDidMount, because that's called when component is loaded, you can leave the constructor as-is, if you need it. constructor is called well before the component is mounted into the DOM.

Comment: I don't understand. Either I create `new ProfileStore(this)` in the `rootStore` or in the `ProfileComponent`, no? Otherwise it'd be duplicated and the `getUserDataFromAPI() ` function will run twice. Should I remove that function from the constructor or should I leave it there? Sorry for asking so many questions. Once this is clarified, I'll give the question as answered by all means

Comment: Oh, sorry for not being clear on that. I would remove that particular  call to `this.profileStore = new ProfileStore(this)` from the constructor and I would execute ProfileStore creation within the `ProfileComponent`'s  `componentDidMount` method. This way, the ProfileStore(this) call will be run only when ProfileComponent is loaded.